# Android Nougat Issue - Webview in a ListFragment - content disappear on scroll

Tags: android, webview, android-listfragment, android-7.0-nougat

I'm loading content into a `WebView`.
This `WebView` is part of a `ListFragment`.
When I `scroll` down (enough so the `WebView` is out of the screen), and then back up, the `content disappears`.
However, this issue only happens on `Nougat (7.0)`, on other android versions it works fine. Does anybody have any idea why this happens and how it can be `fixed`?

Comment: Have you gone through this Have you gone through this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview ?

Comment: I actually didn't know about this, but now that I've read it, I cannot seem to find a workaround... any ideas...?

Comment: share your code

Comment: OK, I did some research on the code (which is huge, and also not all mine) - Apparently on Nougat, "onDetachedFromWindow" is being called on the WebView once it is scrolled out the phone's screen (someone has overridden this method and destroyed the WebView. which makes sense, because the WebView is not supposed to be be there anymore). The question is - why would this method being called on Nougat in the first place?

Comment: what content you are loading in webview? can you share any url on which this issue persist?

Comment: The content type is irrelevant.
As I said before, when the WebView is being scrolled out of the screen, the function onDetachedFromWindow is called. And this happens only on Nougat. Which explains a lot, if you used an override function, and in that function, you destroy the WebView. :)